# Multi-Table Math in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am just starting out in `SQL` which makes searching for simple things difficult because I'm not actually sure what language I should be using.

I am attempting to write an invoice database and am stuck on getting the totals for an order. I have gotten as far as:

```
OrderID Total
6001    $30.00
6002    $75.00
6002    $100.00
6002    $15.00
```

Using:

```
SELECT ORDER.OrderID, [LINE_ITEM].[Quantity]*[PRODUCT].[Cost] AS Total
    FROM (PRODUCT INNER JOIN
           (INVOICE INNER JOIN
              LINE_ITEM
                ON INVOICE.InvoiceID = LINE_ITEM.InvoiceID)
           ON PRODUCT.ProductID = LINE_ITEM.ProductID)
    INNER JOIN [ORDER]
      ON INVOICE.InvoiceID = ORDER.InvoiceID;
```

I would like to have each `OrderID` show the total for each line item assigned to it. So ideally the results would be:

```
OrderID Total
6001    $30.00
6002    $190.00
```

I'm sure this is easy but I've only find ways to do almost-but-not-quite this. Thanks!

Comment: `SUM([LINE_ITEM].[Quantity]*[PRODUCT].[Cost])` and `GROUP BY ORDER.OrderID`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use:

```
SELECT OrderId, Sum(Total) AS Total FROM (<Insert given statement here>) GROUP BY OrderId
```

Comment: Is a nested query required here??

Comment: OK, no it isn't. Make your comment an answer.